# Simple Træfɪk reverse proxy installation

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying the nice [Træfɪk](https://github.com/containous/traefik) reverse proxy with some docker containers.

Here is my Træfɪk **docker-compose.yml**:

```yml
version: '2'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command: --web --docker --docker.domain=my-domain.net --logLevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
```

Here is my services' **docker-compose.yml** web part:

```yml
version: '2'
services:
  # [...]
  web:
    build: . # An nginx based image
    container_name: my_app_web
    volumes:
      - ..:/app/
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=my_app"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my-domain.net"
      - "traefik.port=80"
```

Launching all this stuff, I'm seeing my frontend/backend created on the Træfɪk web UI but I can't access my app by my-domain.net.

```
$ curl -H Host:my-domain.net http://127.0.0.1
# ... after ±30s.
Gateway Timeout
```

Træfɪk log:

> Error forwarding to http://172.18.0.4:80, err: dial tcp 172.18.0.4:80: i/o timeout

I can access the application from it's local IP though (`172.18.0.4`) and it's working fine.

I'm surely forgetting something here, any help ?

---

Additional info:

- The official [`emilevauge/whoami`](https://github.com/EmileVauge/whoamI) is working fine in a separate docker-compose file.
- My service is working fine without Træfɪk (by mapping the port 80)

Comment: Could you please provide the Dockerfile for your web application and a full snippet of your docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Are you running some of the containers in more than one network? then you should also add a label in which network traefik should look for the container. Otherwise you will also see some gateway timeouts. Please provide a full compose file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @AndreasJägle, I inspected the containers and it showed me Traefik and my services in different networks.

I thought by default docker was always using the bridge mode, but it does not seem to the case anymore with [compose networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) starting from v2. It is creating a network for the docker-compose file (based on the project name).

So with compose starting v2, you have to specify a common network by both docker-compose files that need to communicate.

Here, I simply used the one generated for traefik:

```yml
version: '2'
services:
  # ...
  web:
    # ...
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=my_app"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my-domain.net"
      - "traefik.port=80"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: traefik_default
```

---

Additional info:

Traefik was working fine with `emilevauge/whoami` because I was defining a docker-compose v1 file, so it was using the bridge mode.

Answer (score 1):

When you run traefik with docker as a backend, there is no need to expose the ports from your `web` container. So you should be safe to remove the `ports` section from the `web` service in your compose file.

Are you running both services from the same compose file? You must ensure that the traefik container is able to access the web container. This works either when running both from the same compose file or by attaching the two containers to the same network.

Another possibility for a timeout could be your web container exposing more than one port (have a look at your Dockerfile). If this is the case, you need to explicitly tell traefik to which port it should map the requests. In your case this should be `"traefik.port=80"`.

As you are running a very basic setup and you already set the domains using labels, there is no need to provide some special configuration. Please check out the default by just mounting `/dev/null` as toml file like in the [very basic docs](https://docs.traefik.io/#docker).

For the traefik service:

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
```

For your web service

```
labels:
  - "traefik.backend=my_app"
  - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:my-domain.net"
  - "traefik.port=80"
```

Comment: Thank you your detailed answer. Indeed I discovered I didn't need to define any port mapping to my service. Also indeed my container was exposing an additional port and I specified the right one with `traefik.port`. Question updated. However I'm still getting the timeout and no log incoming to my service (nginx)

Comment: I just tried the official `emilevauge/whoami` tiny image in a separate docker-compose file, it is working fine. And my image is working fine without Traefik. I don't know how to debug that.

Comment: could you please provide the output of `docker network ls` and some `docker network inspect <network>` of the networks that are called like the folders where your compose files are located (e.g. for networks named mytest_default if your folder is called something like my-test). I assume that the containers are not able to reach each other.

Comment: I can see my services are not in the same network than Traefik. They are in `myproject_default` network and Traefik is in bridge. I tried to put all my services on bridge, which enables Traefik to communicate with my `web` service but `web` can't communicate with my other services anymore